# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this problem in my Public function Store of Laravel 4, i can upload an update images, pretty cool, but I cannot create a new record :( appears: Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object, in this line:  
 `$filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();`This is complete code.

```
public function store(){

 $image = Input::file('image');`  <br/>
       $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();


        if(Input::hasFile('image')){
            Input::file('image')->move(public_path().'/assets/img/', $filename);
        }

        $titulo = new Titulo();
        $titulo->id             = Input::get('id');
        $titulo->title          = Input::get('title');    
        $titulo->description    = Input::get('description');
        $titulo->date           = Input::get('date');    
        $titulo->image          = $filename;
        $titulo->category_id    = Input::get('category_id');

        $titulo->save();
}
```

### This is my form

```
{{ Form::open (['route' => 'titulos.store', 'class'=> 'form', 'method' =>'post', 'files'=> 'true']) }}

{{ Form::label('title', "Titulo:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}

{{ Form::text('title') }}
    {{ $errors->first('title') }}

<div class="form-group">          
  {{ Form::label('date', "Fecha:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
  <input type="date" name="date" >              
</div>

{{ Form::label('description', "Description:", ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
    {{ Form::textarea('description') }}
    {{ $errors->first('description') }}

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::file('image') }}
</div>

    {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         {{ Form::select('category_id', array('1' => 'TBLeaks', '2' => 'Quejas', '3' => 'Denuncias', '4' => 'Ideas'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
        </div>

    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => "btn btn-primary"]) }}
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('admin') }}">Back to Admin</a>
        </div>          
    </div>  
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `enctype` part. Your open form should be

```
{{ Form::open (['route' => 'titulos.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class'=> 'form', 'method' =>'post', 'files'=> 'true']) }}
```

Comment: OMG!! you @cod3rite are saving my life all the time xoxoxo Thank you again :D